# 'header' and 'buttons' does not exist in type 'ToastOptions' in Ionic 4.1.1, contrary to documentation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing a progressive mobile application using Angular+Ionic.
I wanted to add a couple of toasts that the user could interact with, so I started out by copying the example ionic provides in [their documentation.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast) While their example of a simple "message-only" toast, `presentToast`, works fine for me, I cannot replicate their second example, `presentToastWithOptions`, without getting errors saying that they are using non-existing options.

The example is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'toast-example',
  templateUrl: 'toast-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toast-example.css'],
})
export class ToastExample {

async presentToastWithOptions() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      header: 'Toast header',
      message: 'Click to Close',
      position: 'top',
      buttons: [
        {
          side: 'start',
          icon: 'star',
          text: 'Favorite',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Favorite clicked');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Done',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

The errors I get are

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'header' does not exist in type 'ToastOptions'

and

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'buttons' does not exist in type 'ToastOptions'

The code still runs if I ignore these errors, but I don't get buttons (I don't really care about the header for my purposes). I can only get a button to appear through the `showCloseButton` property, but I wanted to have my button do something other than close the toast :/

Just in case, here's the info about the ionic version I'm working with:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

Comment: try this working sample, =>  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal-vxttcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.page.ts

Comment: @lussac That's weird, it works on the example you provided but if I copy paste it into my app I get the same errors again... I guess it has something to do with my @ionic/angular module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was super simple, I just updated @ionic/angular from version 4.1.1 to version 4.11.10 using `npm update @ionic/angular` :)